# Sonar Qualitygate api based on Severity [blocker/critical/major] not on Type[bugs/vulnerability/code-smells]

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, static-analysis

I am hitting sonar api (**api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=xyz**) from pipeline based on **analysisId** to get the project status. The response recevied is based on `Type[bugs/vulnerability/code-smells]`

Is it possible to get the status based on `Severity [blocker/critical/major]` ?

```
{
  "projectStatus": {
    "status": "ERROR",
    "conditions": [
      {
        "status": "OK",
        "metricKey": "bugs",
        "comparator": "GT",
        "errorThreshold": "0",
        "actualValue": "0"
      },
      {
        "status": "ERROR",
        "metricKey": "vulnerabilities",
        "comparator": "GT",
        "errorThreshold": "0",
        "actualValue": "31"
      },
      {
        "status": "ERROR",
        "metricKey": "code_smells",
        "comparator": "GT",
        "errorThreshold": "0",
        "actualValue": "72"
      }
    ],
    "periods": [

    ],
    "ignoredConditions": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how I got the status, may help someone who is struggling with this issue.

The trick it to use short-lived **branch-name** instead of using the **analysisId** on following api-

```
http://sonardashboard.xxx.com/api/issues/search?componentRoots=<Project-key>&severities=<Type of severity>&branch=<short-lived branch name>
```

Note: This will give issues with status - open and closed. Couldn't filter out using api based on status though.